# Stream Video From Mobile to STB using LAN in Android application

Tags: android, udp, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I want to stream video from my android mobile phone to Android STB using LAN and play video to STB. Something like

**Mobile phones---(wifi)---> Wifi Accesspoint ---(LAN)--->  Android STB.**

How can it be possible..?

Any help is appreciated.